# Acessing properties of a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, path, dns

Is it possible to access the properties of a cookie, such as domain, path, expiry date etc, using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I consider w3schools as the worst suggestion..Why don't you suggest MDN?

Comment: I'm confused, did you look at the functions and decide they don't work?  Or you just don't like the website?

Comment: it works...Actually i think MDN contains more accurate definitions of js properties and functions..Thanks for your suggestion.I know how to set a cookie.I just need to know whether  properties other than value of a cookie is accessible via js?

Answer (score 0):

no its not possible to get those value. The only values you can see for cookie are... whatever you get by doing document.cookie